# Routing with missing app folder in expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-go, expo-router

The simplified [expo router](https://docs.expo.dev/router/introduction/) uses the file name in the app folder to create app routes but creating an expo app using `npx create-expo-app` or `npx create-expo-app@latest` does not result in an app directory. This can also be seen in the [snack browser ide](https://snack.expo.dev/).

I can always clone an exiting repository but  how can I set up the app expo-router on a new project?

Comment: Maybe this link will explain it more? https://docs.expo.dev/router/installation/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the steps mentioned here does not help.

Comment: We can't address issues in code we can't see, so please do [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with. See if you can create a ***running*** [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command:

`npx create-expo-app@latest --template tabs@49`

Be sure to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on StackOverflow and also how to setup a project in [the Expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/create-a-project/).